# Flycheck installation: M-x package-install [No match]

Tags: emacs, flycheck

I'm relatively new to Emacs (and Linux for that matter). I'm trying to install *flycheck*. Following the installation instructions, I added

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
         '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)
```

to my `.emacs` file (then killed Emacs and restarted).

Then `M-x package-install RET flycheck RET`. But Emacs says `[No match]`. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Platform: Emacs 24.3.1, Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit running on VMware (Windows 10 host).

Comment: In no way sure what you are doing wrong or how the whole package stuff is intended to work as I don't use it, but `M-x package-refresh-contents` before `M-x package-install RET flycheck RET` should do the job.

Comment: @mikyra Well apparently you _did_ know what I was doing wrong :-) Would have been nice for flycheck to have included this in their install instructions. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm also quite new to emacs, and I've had the same problem. What worked for me:

1. `M-x package-list-packages RET`
2. Find `flycheck`, mark it with an `I`
3. Use `X` to install marked package.

For reference, this is how I call `package` in my `.emacs`:

```
(require 'package) 
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa-stable" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/"))
(when (< emacs-major-version 24)
  ;; For important compatibility libraries like cl-lib
  (add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))
(package-initialize)`
```

Comment: Thanks Peter -- looks like we're in this together ;-) The `package-list-packages` command is good to know. Regarding your `.emacs` file, I think the part that starts with `when` is only needed if you're running Emacs 23 or lower.

Comment: I think you're right. Thanks for the tip! Always looking to clean up my `.emacs` :)

Comment: For me it says, "I is undefined".